# How to retrieve key and value from JSON file using stream option in jq

Tags: json, stream, jq

I have a json file with structure like this:

```
 {
    "A": [{
        "B": {
            "C": [{
                "D": {
                    "applicationNumberText": {
                        "value": "15570075",
                        "electronicText": "15570075"
                    },
                    "date": "2018-10-01",
                    "app": "Utility"
                }
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

Now I want to retrieve `electronicText` value. One way is to use indexes like following

```
jq --stream 'select(.[0][1] == "A" and .[0][2] == "B" and .[0][3] == "C") | .[1]'
```

but the structure may differ in some cases so I want to refer by key values instead of indexes. I tried following method but it's not working

```
cat file.json | jq --stream 'select(.A|.[]. B. C|.[]. D.applicationNumberText)'
```

So I want to retrieve `electronicText`  key  without using indexes.

`Note`: I want to use `stream` option for large JSON file.

Comment: Your first jq query uses key names that do not even appear in the JSON. Please fix. Also, the description of the problem is very sketchy and seems to differ from the title. Please follow [mcve] and indicate whether the value of .electronicText is known to be a scalar.

Comment: The JSON isn't a valid one. Fix it from jsonlint.com

Comment: @Inian Thanks for your valuable response I had made some changes in JSON please go through this.

Comment: @peak I had just corrected the key names please go through this. Thanks for your valuable opinion.

Answer (score 2):

If the indexes of the arrays are fixed, you can use this filter:

```
jq '.A[0].B.C[0].D.applicationNumberText.electronicText' file
```

and to extract all `electronicText` fields, you can use this:

```
jq '.A[].B.C[].D.applicationNumberText.electronicText' file
```

If you want to use the jq stream fashion (though it's not clear why), you can use this:

```
jq --stream 'select(.[0]|contains(["electronicText"]))|.[1]//empty'
```

This will look in the key path for the string `electronicText` and if found, get its associated value. The `//empty` is to filter out the path array without value.

Comment: This returns only values of `electronicText` key but I want key as well as value . Can you help me out from this? and I also want to change key name and assign this value to new key name.
Ex: electronicText :1890 
I want "appnumber":1890

Comment: I'm not able to fetch multi keys value like `value` key and `electronicText` key. Can you help me out?

Comment: @vikash It's unclear to me what you want exactly. You might look for something like `jq --stream '{"appnumber": (select(.[0]|contains(["electronicText"]))|.[1]//empty)}' file` ...

Comment: @vikash It's not a good idea to change the scope of the question. Instead please create a new question where you state clearly what's your new problem.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience but i want to fetch multi-keys and it's values.
 In this question I want `value` and `electronicText` key's value. I hope you better understand.

Comment: @vikash You're changing the scope of the original question. Please close this question (by accepting one of the answers) and ask another one.

Comment: `jq --stream '{"appnumber": (select(.[0]|contains(["electronicText"]))|.[1]//empty)}'`
This helps me a lot ,i want same thing but more than one key clubbed in to single dictionary like
`{"appnumber":1717,
   "value":1717
}`
I hope you better understand oliv.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I belive what you are looking for is:

```
. as $inputs | {} | setpath($inputs[0]; $inputs[1]) | .A[]?.B.C[]?.D.applicationNumberText.electronicText // empty
```

This filter expects `--stream` as a flag (like your first example), generates a temporal obj with a section of the json, runs the filter based on your second example, and then hides the null results.  Note: [This based on a example in the cookbook](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook#processing-huge-json-texts)

Let me give you an overview of the things at play in case it is confusing:

1. [The `--stream` flag will make your receive your data differently](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/#Streaming). You filter will now run multiple times with data in the form of `[<path>, <leaf-value>]` which is received as the parser traverses your json file, one node at a time.

   I believe you refer to this when you mention using indexes, in this case meanining that you are inspecting the `path expression value` that the `--streaming flag` exposes instead of the *actual* json data.

   Please compare the outputs of the following:

   ```
   jq '.A[].B.C[].D.applicationNumberText.electronicText' file.json # outputs 15570075 
   jq --stream '.A[].B.C[].D.applicationNumberText.electronicText' file.json # multiple failures: cannot index array with string "A"
   ```
2. [setpath()](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#setpath(PATHS;VALUE)) receives these path and leaf-value parameters puts it on top of its input object. e.g.

   ```
   {} | setpath(["a", 0, "b"], "leaf-value") # returns {"a":[{"b":"leaf-value"}]}
   ```

   in our case we are generating the following stream of values as the parse visits each node:

   ```
   {"A":[{"B":{"C":[{"D":{"applicationNumberText":{"value":"15570075"}}}]}}]}
   {"A":[{"B":{"C":[{"D":{"applicationNumberText":{"electronicText":"15570075"}}}]}}]}
   {"A":[{"B":{"C":[{"D":{"applicationNumberText":{"electronicText":null}}}]}}]}
   {"A":[{"B":{"C":[{"D":{"date":"2018-10-01"}}]}}]}
   {"A":[{"B":{"C":[{"D":{"app":"Utility"}}]}}]}
   ```
3. Now that the data has a format similar to the json file we can run a more familiar filter.

   ```
   .A[]?.B.C[]?.D.applicationNumberText.electronicText
   ```

   keep in mind that there are no spaces between. We are also using the `?` operator on both generator `.A[]` and `.C[]` because we are not sure that those fields will be available as arrays at all times

As a final note, you might want to consider building a path array with [`path()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#path(path_expression)) and compare that against the path value that appears in `.[0]` when using the `--stream` jq flag

Comment: Can you give me exact direction for retrieve multi-keys values like `value` and  `electronicText` using `stream`?

Comment: @vikash I wrote an example [in this gist over in github](https://gist.github.com/nhtzr/ee1860ce665553e59f9a99db57b3a109) with some explanation. If that shows to be unclear, please create another question about multi value retrieval

Answer (score 1):

In response to the original question:

```
jq --stream '
  select(length==2 and .[0][-1]=="electronicText")|.[1]
' input.json
"15570075"
```

If you want the `value` as well, then you might wish to consider the following filter:

```
select(length==2 and .[0][-2]=="applicationNumberText")
| .[0][-1] as $last
| select($last == "electronicText" or $last == "value")
| {($last): .[1]}
```

which with your sample JSON produces:

```
{"value":"15570075"}
{"electronicText":"15570075"}
```

### Combining key-value pairs into a single JSON object

One way to construct a "dictionary" is to use `inputs` in conjunction with the -n command-line option.  Simply wrap the above filter in the structure:

```
 [inputs | ....] | add
```

where here .... stands for the above filter; and invoke jq with *both* the -n and --stream options.

Comment: Thanks! it's works but i want both `value` and `electronicText`  or more key's value clubbed in to one dictionary can you help me out?
Ex:
`{"appnumber":1717, "value":1717,"key":corresponding values  }` etc.

Comment: @vikash - You asked for a dictionary, so that's what the query using `inputs` yields.  If you want to add further key/value pairs, you'll have to do some understanding. SO is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the objects of interest, just search for object paths by name.

```
getpath(paths(objects) | select(.[-1] == "applicationNumberText"))
```

---

Streaming the input in should help with efficiency concerns. Just identify the paths you want to keep and truncate the paths of interest.

```
$ jq -n --stream --arg key 'applicationNumberText' '
fromstream(inputs | truncate_stream2((.[0] | index($key) // empty) + 1))
' input.json
```

This just checks the path and looks for the `"applicationNumberText"` key then truncates the path to that value so it can be rebuilt from the stream.

This uses an inverted version of the [`truncate_stream/1`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#truncate_stream(stream_expression)) function which swaps the usual inputs which I find using more intuitive.

```
def truncate_stream2($count): .[0] |= .[$count:];
```

Comment: `jq: error: truncate_stream2/1 is not defined at <top-level>, line 2:`
I got this error